# How to put text into a segue function to pass to next controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I want to take the title and put it as titleText in the DestVC which is a label. How do I put it in the segue function?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import SDWebImage


struct postStruct {
    let title : String!
    let author : String!
    let date : String!
    let article : String!
    let downloadURL : String!

}

class ZeroHomeViewController: UITableViewController {




var posts = [postStruct]()
var  downloadURL : String = ""






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Posts")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.childrenCount)

        for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

            guard let value = rest.value as? Dictionary<String,Any> else { continue }

            guard let  title = value["Title"] as? String else { continue }
            guard let  downloadURL = value["Download URL"] as? String else { continue }
            guard let  author = value["Author"] as? String else { continue }
            guard let  date = value["Date"] as? String else { continue }
            guard let  article = value["Article"] as? String else { continue }


            let post = postStruct(title: title, author: author, date: date, article: article, downloadURL: downloadURL)

            self.posts.append(post)


        }

        self.posts = self.posts.reversed(); self.tableView.reloadData()

    })


}




override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title


    let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    let post = self.posts[indexPath.row];
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: post.downloadURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))

 return cell!

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destVC = segue.destination as! ArticleViewController
            destVC.titleText = value["Title"] as? String

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: `destVC.titleText = value["Title"] as? String` ?

Comment: it's not working. says ambiguous reference to member 'value(forKey:)'

Comment: What is `value`?  You haven't shown where/what that is in your code

Comment: i updated my question. I put the entire code.

Comment: That helps a lot.

Comment: i dont understand this :(

Comment: I meant that seeing all of the relevant code helps me understand your problem so I can provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to access the relevant `postStruct` from your `posts` array and then get the title.  You already have the index path for the selected row; the `.row` property will be the index in your `posts` array for the struct you need.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let destVC = segue.destination as! ArticleViewController
            destVC.titleText = posts[indexPath.row].title

        }

    }
}
```